# Is "EF BF BF" an allowed character in XML (UTF-8)?

Tags: xml, utf-8, character

Is "EF BF BF" an allowed character in XML (UTF-8)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<XML>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <CONTENT>" "</CONTENT>
    </DOCUMENT>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "EF **BF** BF" is a typo, and you meant "EF **BB** BF":

Yes, if it is the first bytes. They are the "BOM", [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), used to identify the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the file.

<strike>For UTF-16 and UTF-32-encoded files this is mandatory.</strike>

For UTF-8, this is optional. Some systems might be confused by it if it is present, and it might give unexpected behavior if an UTF-8-file with BOM is used in a context expecting for example ISO-8859-1.

**Edit**:
If "EF BF BF" isn't a typo, it is [not valid UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffff/index.htm) anywhere in the file.

Comment: Correct as regards to the question asked, but BOM is not mandatory in UTF-16 and UTF-32. Ref.: Unicode Standard, Ch. 3, http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch03.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It's the UTF-8 representation of "Replacement character" : https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

Comment: No, that is 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD. Where did you get "0xBD" from? A typo? The one here is 0xEF 0xBF 0xBF (which is U+FFFF, the very last one: *"[<noncharacter-FFFF> not a character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block))"* (whatever that means)

Comment: Is this a bogus answer?