# PHP json_encode returns null

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I believe this was caused by this character: `%EF%BF%BD`, `%uFFFD`, or `�`
other special chars are working fine like `%E2%98%86`, `%u2606`, or `☆`

What I am doing it dumping mp3 file tag data with getid3 via ajax, I can work around this by removing the property that has this character as i am not using that part, but I would rather have the character not break my script

```
require_once('/usr/share/php/getid3/getid3.php');
$getID3=new getID3;
die(json_encode((object)array("id3"=>$getID3->analyze($file)['tags']['id3v2'],"other"=>"data"));
```

From what I have managed to figure out I would guess this character is not a UTF-8 character, so aside from doing something ugly like looping through every property name and property and using [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) on it rebuilding the data is there a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: `\ufffd` isn't the problem, it's the symptom. It means that wherever that character occurs it has replaced a broken UTF8 sequence in the input data, [but chances are you're just interpreting as the wrong charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). [ID3v2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2) allows for several different encodings, so you're going to have to detect and translate.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510366/2943403

Comment: See edit at end of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310227/2943403